# UTF-8 encoded Japanese character is not properly displayed on Rstudio console

Tags: r, utf-8, character-encoding, rstudio, tibble

I'm a Japanese R user working on macOS 10.15.7 and RStudio 1.4.1103, R 4.0.4.
I imported a UTF-8 encoded Japanese character as a character object from an external source. When I try to print it on the console, the character codes are displayed. However, when I convert it to a tibble and try to print it, I can see the Japanese characters.
What is the cause of the difference, and is it possible to display the Japanese characters for the former case?

(reproducible example)

```r
library(tidyverse)
ja_txt <- "\u98df\u4e8b"
print(ja_txt)
#> [1] "\u98df\u4e8b"
ja_txt %>% enframe() %>% print()
#> # A tibble: 1 x 2
#>    name value
#>   <int> <chr>
#> 1     1 食事
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

**Update**
As I mentioned in my comments, actually I imported the text from a UTF-8 encoded CSV file created on MS Excel. I tried both importing from CSV file and from xlsx file, both of which did not work well, as is shown in the image below.

[image: RStudio console image of Japanese characters]

```r
df <- structure(list(col1 = "\u98df\u4e8b"), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(col1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Hello yh6. This is very likely a condition (or feature or "problem") of your operating system's locale. What you describe, a string in the console showing UTF-8 encoded characters as "\u###" is typical of MS Windows running its default Windows-1252 encoding. The package `tibble` in Windows manages to display the characters in the corresponding glyph/kanji, but base R does not.
If you run your code in a UTF-8 encoding OS, you will get the expected glyph. OsX and Linux encode by default in UTF-8.

Comment: See this: https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/05/02/utf-8-support-on-windows/

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez Thank you very much for your comments. Actually I'm working on macOS but the "problem" occurs. Is it because I imported the characters from a UTF-8 encoded CSV file created by MS Excel?

Comment: I am not sure.  Have you tried reading the Excel file from R?
I ran your code verbatim in Linux (ubuntu with UTF-8 encoding) and the kanjis displayed as expected .

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez Thank you, I tried it but it produces the same result. Please check the update of my question.